# Is there a way to use a pre-existing photo or video as a live camera input

Tags: image, photo

If it is possible please let me know.

All i wanted is to use a pre-existing photo or video as a live camera input.

Comment: Absolutely yes. There are ways from various programming languages, and some apps that can. For example, see [this guide](https://obsproject.com/kb/virtual-camera-guide) using OBS. In general, the term to search for would be "virtual camera" - e.g., "python virtual camera"